# loop through nested js object and append div with custom html using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

Im not even sure if I worded the title of what I need correctly, but in a nutshell, I'm trying to loop through a nested js object, extract specific values, combine them with an html template, then append a Div with the result (for an ecommerce site uing snipcart).

This is my code at the moment (which clearly doesnt work)

```
var comics = {
    modern: {
        1: {
            "data-item-id" : "pun-224",
            "data-item-price" : "3.49",
            "data-item-url" : "/",
            "data-item-description" : "The Punisher issue 224",
            "data-item-image" : "/img/modern.jpg",
            "data-item-name" : "The punisher 224"
        },
        2:{
            "data-item-id" : "pun-225",
            "data-item-price" : "3.49",
            "data-item-url" : "/",
            "data-item-description" : "The Punisher issue 224",
            "data-item-image" : "/img/silver.jpg",
            "data-item-name" : "The punisher 225"
        }
            

    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("hello");
$.each(comics.modern, function() {
    
        var list = $("#comic__list");
        list.append(
            `<button 
            class="snipcart-add-item" 
            data-item-id="${this.data-item-id}" 
            data-item-price="${this.data-item-id}" 
            data-item-url="${this.data-item-id}" 
            data-item-description="${this.data-item-id}" 
            data-item-image="${this.data-item-id}" 
            data-item-name="${this.data-item-id}"> 
            Add to cart
            </button>`
        )    

    
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Object.keys to get the object keys as array and then you can loop through it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.each(Object.keys(comics.modern), function() {
    var currentObject = comics.modern[this];
    var list = $("#comic__list");
    list.append(
         `<button 
            class="snipcart-add-item" 
            data-item-id="${currentObject['data-item-id']}" 
            data-item-price="${currentObject['data-item-id']}" 
            data-item-url="${currentObject['data-item-id']}" 
            data-item-description="${currentObject['data-item-id']}" 
            data-item-image="${currentObject['data-item-id']}" 
            data-item-name="${currentObject['data-item-id']}"> 
            Add to cart
         </button>`
     )   
    
});
});
```

Note: you cannot use object.property-of-the-object when the property contains a dash, instead use object['property-of-the-object']